# Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.9.2 unable to load symbols from the Microsoft symbol server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.9.2 and I am trying to debug something in C#. I wanted to load symbols but my symbol cache is totally empty despite me having configured Visual Studio correctly.

[image]

When I explicitly load symbols for the **Unity.Mvc.dll** assembly that I am interested in by selecting **Load Symbols** from the **Modules** pane while debugging, it attempts the download ultimately displaying **Cannot find or open the PDB file.** in the **Symbol Status** window.

[image]

The **Symbol Load Information** dialog reports as follows.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\385c2246\beb904df\assembly\dl3\91f61dc3\00610fa0_6b3fd401\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. C:\projects\aspnet-mvc\src\obj\Release\net45\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. C:\Windows\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. C:\Windows\symbols\dll\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. C:\Windows\dll\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\Unity.Mvc.pdb\41297c5a10a2446ba7397343f3dbad86ffffffff\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\Unity.Mvc.pdb\41297c5a10a2446ba7397343f3dbad86ffffffff\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\Unity.Mvc.pdb\41297c5a10a2446ba7397343f3dbad861\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\Unity.Mvc.pdb\41297c5a10a2446ba7397343f3dbad861\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. C:\Sathyaish\repos\private\sathyaish.net\Code\Unity.Mvc.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x3
         C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         Unity.Mvc.pdb
         41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD86ffffffff SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\Unity.Mvc.pdb\41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD86ffffffff\Unity.Mvc.pdb
- path not found SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\Unity.Mvc.pdb\41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD86ffffffff\Unity.Mvc.pd_
- path not found SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\Unity.Mvc.pdb\41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD86ffffffff\file.ptr
- path not found SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/Unity.Mvc.pdb/41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD86ffffffff/Unity.Mvc.pdb SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/Unity.Mvc.pdb/41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD86ffffffff/Unity.Mvc.pd_ SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/Unity.Mvc.pdb/41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD86ffffffff/file.ptr SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194 SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x4
         C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         Unity.Mvc.pdb
         41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD861 SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\Unity.Mvc.pdb\41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD861\Unity.Mvc.pdb
- path not found SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\Unity.Mvc.pdb\41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD861\Unity.Mvc.pd_
- path not found SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\Unity.Mvc.pdb\41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD861\file.ptr
- path not found SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/Unity.Mvc.pdb/41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD861/Unity.Mvc.pdb SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/Unity.Mvc.pdb/41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD861/Unity.Mvc.pd_ SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/Unity.Mvc.pdb/41297C5A10A2446BA7397343F3DBAD861/file.ptr SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194 https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.
```

This isn't the first time this is happening. I usually solve this one every few years and forget how I did it.

Comment: 3rd party PDBs are not on symbol sever. Open a [new issue](https://github.com/unitycontainer/aspnet-mvc/issues/new) and request [Sourcelink](https://blog.nuget.org/20180827/Introducing-Source-Code-Link-for-NuGet-packages.html) or [NuGet symbol server](https://blog.nuget.org/20181116/Improved-debugging-experience-with-the-NuGet-org-symbol-server-and-snupkg.html) support

Comment: Unity is [no longer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/) a Microsoft property, so zero odds you'll find the PDBs on Microsoft's symbol server.  Consider building from source available at github.

Comment: Thank you. You're both right. https://github.com/unitycontainer/aspnet-mvc/issues/9